# How does Laravel know Request::wantsJson is a request for JSON?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I noticed that Laravel has a neat method [`Request::wantsJson`](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/requests) - I assume when I make the request I can pass information to request a JSON response, but how do I do this, and what criteria does Laravel use to detect whether a request asks for JSON ?

Answer (score 75, accepted):

It uses the `Accept` header sent by the client to determine if it wants a JSON response.

Let's look at [the code](https://github.com/illuminate/http/blob/ded46979debbc9b03660503f54c962ba51b1a209/Concerns/InteractsWithContentTypes.php#L52) :

```
public function wantsJson() {
    $acceptable = $this->getAcceptableContentTypes();
    return isset($acceptable[0]) && $acceptable[0] == 'application/json';
}
```

So if the client sends a request with the first acceptable content type to `application/json` then the method will return true.

As for how to request JSON, you should set the `Accept` header accordingly, it depends on what library you use to query your route, here are some examples with libraries I know :

[Guzzle](http://guzzle.readthedocs.org) (PHP):

```
GuzzleHttp\get("http://laravel/route", ["headers" => ["Accept" => "application/json"]]);
```

[cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) (PHP) :

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, [CURLOPT_URL => "http://laravel/route", CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => ["Accept" => "application/json"], CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true]);
curl_exec($curl);
```

[Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) (Python) :

```
requests.get("http://laravel/route", headers={"Accept":"application/json"})
```

Comment: Usually you want to use [$request->expectsJson()](https://laravel.com/api/6.x/Illuminate/Http/Concerns/InteractsWithContentTypes.html#method_expectsJson) instead. This is will also check if you have received an AJAX request.

Comment: Dart/Flutter: `var headers = Map<String, String>(); headers.putIfAbsent(HttpHeaders.acceptHeader, () => 'application/json');`

Comment: can you put an example with `Request::create()` in laravel ?