# Different Response(JSON and webpage) in API and Website for Laravel 404 and 500?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

I want to show the different response for API and website. In api response I want to show json response with 404 and 500 for type of exception mainly for routes.

If a user try to request a route and route not found I want to show a response in json response for API and webpage for website.

I know and try the code into `app/Exceptions/Handler.php`

```
public function render($request, Exception $exception)
{
    if ($exception instanceof NotFoundHttpException) {
        if ($request->expectsJson()) {
            return response()->json(['error' => 'Not Found'], 404);
        }
        return response()->view('404', [], 404);
    }
    return parent::render($request, $exception);
}
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/errors#http-exceptions

but failed can anybody help me how can I set different responses for error pages.

Comment: For Laravel 8, see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/60671373/9053821

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Expects `JSON` is about headers, i do not like that solution for `API` errors, you can access the `API` through a browser. My solution is most of the times to filter by the `URL` route, because it starts with `"api/..."`, which can be done like so `$request->is('api/*')`.

If you have your routes that are not prefixes with `/api`, then this will not work. Change the logic to fit with your own structure.

```
public function render($request, Exception $exception)
{
    if ($exception instanceof NotFoundHttpException) {
        if ($request->is('api/*')) {
            return response()->json(['error' => 'Not Found'], 404);
        }
        return response()->view('404', [], 404);
    }
    return parent::render($request, $exception);
}
```

Comment: This works for me, also add ```use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException;``` Thankyou

Answer (score 4):

Just wanted to add an alternative to the above answers, which all seem to work as well.

After having the same problem and digging deeper, I took a slightly different approach:

- your exception handle calls `parent::render(...)`. If you look into that function, it will render a json response if your request indicates that it `wantsJson()` [see [hints how that works here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26532180/10615745)]
- now, to turn all responses (including exceptions) to json I used the Jsonify Middleware idea from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35319899/10615745), but applied it to the api MiddlewareGroup, which is by default assigned to RouteServiceProvider::mapApiRoutes()

Here is one way to implement it (very similar to referenced answer from above):

1. Create the file `app/Http/Middleware/Jsonify.php`

   ```
   <?php

   namespace App\Http\Middleware;

   use Closure;

   class Jsonify
   {
       /**
        * Handle an incoming request.
        *
        * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
        * @param  \Closure  $next
        * @return mixed
        */
       public function handle($request, Closure $next)
       {
           if ( $request->is('api/*') ) {
               $request->headers->set('Accept', 'application/json');
           }
           return $next($request);
       }
   }
   ```
2. Add the middleware reference to your $routeMiddleware table of your `app/Http/Kernel.php` file:

   ```
       protected $routeMiddleware = [
       ...
          'jsonify' => \App\Http\Middleware\Jsonify::class,
       ...
       ];
   ```
3. In that same Kernel file, add the jsonify name to the api group:

   ```
   protected $middlewareGroups = [
   ...
     'api' => [
       'jsonify',
       'throttle:60,1',
       'bindings',            
     ],
   ...
   ];
   ```

Result is that the middleware gets loaded for any requests that fall into the 'api' group. If the request url begins with `api/` (which is slightly redundant I think)  then the header gets added by the Jsonify Middleware. This will tell the ExceptionHandler::render() that we want a json output.

Comment: Sadly, this works most of the time, but for some cases it will not work: if you get a "not-authorized" from a policy or gate, then your middleware may not have been loaded yet. Without jsonify loaded, you will get non-json output unless you set your headers accordingly (Accept Application/Json). So you can use this answer, just beware of the shortfalls...

Comment: If you're adding this to the `api` middleware group, there's no need to check for `/api` in the request URL. The routing service provider applies the `api` middleware group and the `/api` prefix to routes listed in `api.php`.

Answer (score 1):

No need to hustle again for Laravel upgrade. You just need to define this method in the ***routes/api.php***

```
Route::fallback(function(){
    return response()->json(['message' => 'Not Found!'], 404);
});
```

Comment: This works fine with GET method. but same url with othre methods (POST, PUT, ...) wrill return 405 MethodNotAlowed. I recommend to define custom fallback route in end of your api route by this way(https://stackoverflow.com/a/47537029/6807353)

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Laravel 5.5.28, and am adding this in `app/Exceptions/Handler.php`

```
public function render($request, Exception $exception)
{
    // Give detailed stacktrace error info if APP_DEBUG is true in the .env
    if ($request->wantsJson()) {
      // Return reasonable response if trying to, for instance, delete nonexistent resource id.
      if ($exception instanceof \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException) {
        return response()->json(['data' => 'Resource not found'], 404);
      }
      if ($_ENV['APP_DEBUG'] == 'false') {
        return response()->json(['error' => 'Unknown error'], 400);
      }
    }
    return parent::render($request, $exception);
}
```

This expects that your API calls will be having a header with key `Accept` and value `application/json`.

Then a nonexistent web route returns the expected

> Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found

and a nonexistent API resource returns a JSON 404 payload.

Found the [info here](https://www.toptal.com/laravel/restful-laravel-api-tutorial).

You could combine this with the answer looking for the instance of `NotFoundHttpException` to catch the 500. I imagine, however, that the stack trace would be preferred.

Answer (score 0):

finally found this for 9.x

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException;
 
/**
 * Register the exception handling callbacks for the application.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function register()
{
    $this->renderable(function (NotFoundHttpException $e, $request) {
        if ($request->is('api/*')) {
            return response()->json([
                'message' => 'Record not found.'
            ], 404);
        }
    });
}
```

source: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/errors#rendering-exceptions

Answer (score -1):

`try this.`

```
public function render($request, Exception $exception)
    {
        if ($request->ajax()) {
            return \Response::json([
                'success' => false,
                'message' => $exception->getMessage(),
            ], $exception->getCode());
        } else {
            return parent::render($request, $exception);
        }
    }
```

Comment: "X-Requested-With":"XMLHttpReques"  need to add  in header otherwise laravel request not detect as ajex call that why return a page.