# Laravel error Declaration of App\Exceptions\Handler::report(Throwable $exception)

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using Laravel 6 and getting the following error when deploying to a shared host running PHP 7.3:

```
App\Exceptions\Handler::report(Throwable $exception)
```

> Declaration of App\Exceptions\Handler::report(Throwable $exception) must be compatible with Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler::report(Exception $e) in /home/kb2hm3y8r4wm/public_html/laravel.supremeanimation.com/app/Exceptions/Handler.php on line 8

Answer (score 68, accepted):

I think the error you're getting is due to changes on Laravel 7 (not 6), as you can see on [Laravel 7 upgrade guide](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/upgrade#symfony-5-related-upgrades). Check this:

- For Laravel < 7:

  > The report and render methods of your application's
  >   `App\Exceptions\Handler` class should accept instances of the
  >   `Exception` interface instead of `Throwable` instances:

  ```php
  use Exception;

  public function report(Exception $exception);
  public function render($request, Exception $exception);
  ```
- For Laravel >= 7:

  > The report and render methods of your application's
  >   `App\Exceptions\Handler` class should accept instances of the
  >   `Throwable` interface instead of `Exception` instances:

  ```php
  use Throwable;

  public function report(Throwable $exception);
  public function render($request, Throwable $exception);
  ```

Comment: it's working on my local server but when i full here on shared hosting it's not work and one more thing my artisan commands are also not working

Comment: @KamaljeetSingh check your `laravel/framework` version on `composer.json` file, what is it on your host/server?

Comment: @HaferDivandari 
i am using godaddy ultimate hosting aisa server 

"php": "^7.2",
        "cnvs/canvas": "^5.2",
        "fideloper/proxy": "^4.0",
        "fruitcake/laravel-cors": "^1.0",
        "laravel/framework": "^6.2",
        "laravel/socialite": "^4.3",
        "laravel/tinker": "^2.0",
        "laravel/ui": "^1.2",
        "nesbot/carbon": "^2.31"

Comment: and getting error in cli whenever i run  composer install i got "Script @php artisan package:discover --ansi handling the post-autoload-dump event returned with error code 255"

Comment: Thanks!
This helped me fix the error that I had after updating to lumen 7

Comment: I am using Lumen 8 version. I have added this code in `Handler.php` file `if($exception->getStatusCode() == 404){
                return response(view("errors.404"), 404);
            }` it is coming in 404 if condition but not rendering the view. Could you please suggest me what is the issue. Thanks a lot.

Comment: while I have added `404.blade.php` file in `resources/views/errors` folder. Any suggestion?

Comment: @Kamlesh revert your changes on `Handler.php`, it is not necessary. Creating a `resources/views/errors/404.blade.php` file is enough to customize HTTP 404 Error Page. This file will be served on all 404 errors generated by your application.

Comment: @HafezDivandari Thanks a lot for your quick reply. My handler is same as https://github.com/laravel/lumen/blob/8.x/app/Exceptions/Handler.php and I have created `404.blade.php` and `500.blade.php` files with writing dummy text to test in it. but still getting same response eg. `Oops! An Error Occurred
The server returned a "500 Internal Server Error".
Something is broken. Please let us know what you were doing when this error occurred. We will fix it as soon as possible. Sorry for any inconvenience caused.` Kindly suggest what is wrong? Am I missing something? Help me. Thanks a lot.